# Laravel - Vue. Como puedo hacer que una columna de una tabla de resultado tenga varios formatos (a veces es un porcentaje, después un decimal, ..etc)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, formato

Cordial saludo,se que con filtros (valor | number(0.0)) puedo cambiar el formato de un valor en una tabla, tengo un numerador y un denominador,muchas veces el formato depende de que se le asigne a un indicador, por ejemplo un indicador se puede medir en porcentajes(%),otro en decimales(0.89) o en tasas(a/b*1000). Como puedo hacer para que sea dinámico dependiendo de un propiedad que se llama unidad_de_medida la cual me dice que formato debe tener.

```
<td> {{(medicionindicador.numerador / medicionindicador.denominador) | number('0.0')}} </td>
```

Comment: La manera mas simple que veo es crear una propiedad computada y validar la unidad_de_medida y retornar lo que necesites

Comment: si no lo había visto así,a veces tenemos la respuesta en nuestras narices, te cuento como me fue y gracias por contestar